# Which SQL is Better? on MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, mysql5

In MySQL INSERT

1. REPLACE INTO
2. INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Which SQL is Better? 
Could you give me a advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you're doing with them.  `REPLACE INTO` is technically faster since it doesn't have to do a read before updating (but that is mostly irrelevant), but I've felt that `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is generally more clear as to what you want to do.

Here is a [short discussion in a blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/18/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-replace-into/).